# How to extract letters except from middle part by using slice operator in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

I was trying to understand below example with all possibilities.

```
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | C | O | M | P | U | T | E | R | S |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
 -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1 

  COMPUTERS[ 4 : 7 ]     =  UTE
  COMPUTERS[ 2 : 5 : 2 ] =  MU
  COMPUTERS[-5 : 1 :-1 ] =  UPM
  COMPUTERS[ 4 ]         =  U
  COMPUTERS[-4 :-6 :-1 ] =  TU
  COMPUTERS[ 2 :-3 : 1 ] =  MPUT
  COMPUTERS[ 2 :-3 :-1 ] =  
  COMPUTERS[   :   :-1 ] =  SRETUPMOC
  COMPUTERS[-5 :   ]     =  UTERS
  COMPUTERS[-5 : 0 :-1 ] =  UPMO
  COMPUTERS[-5 :   :-1 ] =  UPMOC
  COMPUTERS[-1 : 1 :-2 ] =  SEUM
```

But I didn't get How to take letters other than middle three

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
Ex:
COMPUTERS =  COMERS (only first three and last three not the middle three letters (PUT))
```

Could someone tell me how to take letters from start and end (:3 and 6:)

Comment: What if the string has lesser than three characters? Also, with single slicing you cannot get two strings. So, you need to do two slicing and join them

Comment: Just add two slices together - `word[:3] + word[-3:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not one slice, that's two slices:

```
word[:3] + word[-3:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy into a list, delete the middle, then convert back:

```
>>> computers = list('COMPUTERS')
>>> del computers[3:-3]
>>> ''.join(computers)
COMERS
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the middle part of string you must use two slice:

```
>>> string="COMPUTERS"
>>> string[:len(string)//3]+string[-len(string)//3:]
'COMERS'
```